# Get and pass into container the host IP address

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I have a container running a service and a rails application that is not containerized (running on the host).

The service needs to call an endpoint in the rails application running on the host.

I know I can start the container with the `-e` option and pass it an IP address.

How can I get the IP address of the host machine as seen from inside the container (assuming that it could be dynamic)?

Comment: If you can get your rails application listening on the `docker0` interface (normally 172.17.0.1), then it can be directly accessed from the container.

Comment: you should run your rails app inside a container also and --link from one container to the other EXPOSE ing the relevant ports as necessary in your Dockerfile